# ROW_NUMBER applied not in sequence of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, sequence

**USING SQL SERVER 2012**
I have a requirement in which I have to clean the source slightly to get the desired output.

I have Vehicle Name, GPSTime, Login/Logoff, DriverID as columns.
Because source data is not clean, we are trying to generate a table out of this which is cleaner with each login having a subsequent logoff.

I have a data like below

```
Vehicle         GPS      Login/Logoff  Driver
```

`Veh1     28-01-2016 06:30   Login       D1
Veh1      28-01-2016 06:35   Login       D1
Veh1      28-01-2016 06:40   Login       D1
Veh1      28-01-2016 09:40   Logoff      D1
Veh1      28-01-2016 10:30   Login       D2
Veh1      28-01-2016 12:30   Logoff      D2
Veh1      28-01-2016 15:30   Login       D1
Veh1      28-01-2016 17:30   Logoff      D1`

I am trying to get the output as

`Veh1      28-01-2016 06:30   Login   D1 --> Tricky bit to take the first login
 Veh1      28-01-2016 09:40   Logoff  D1
 Veh1      28-01-2016 10:30   Login   D2
 Veh1      28-01-2016 12:30   Logoff  D2
 Veh1      28-01-2016 15:30   Login   D1
 Veh1      28-01-2016 17:30   Logoff  D1`

I tried the approach of row_number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DriverID ORDER BY GPSTime asc) but whatever i do its putting a sequence number for all login for that driver continuously though its not the adjacent row. I was planning on using the required sequence number to enhance the logic to derive the desired output.

Is there any other way ? Any suggestions would help.

Regards,
Jo

Comment: Another words you want to find start and end periods of a range and remove all the values in between.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't have the logoff as another column in the same row?

Comment: Hogan, once i have the sequence correctly, i can get to that.. was only thinking about cleaning it at the moment so that every login has a corresponding logoff and consider other exception data also.

Comment: @JoSam as you see in my answer it is actually easier to get that than to return two rows.  SQL does not work like other languages where adding something in an order is adding an output in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not very clear, but it sounds like you want to remove rows that are consecutive logins or logoffs (per driver?), and only keep the first row when the login/logoff status changes.

If that is the case, then using the `lag()` window function can come in pretty handy.

Here is a query that can give you an idea of how to get this done:

```
select t.vehicle, t.gps, t.login_logoff, t.driver
  from (select t.*,
               case 
                 when lag(login_logoff) 
                     over (partition by driver 
                               order by gps) = login_logoff
                 then 1 else 0 end as is_duplicate_row
          from tbl t) t
 where t.is_duplicate_row = 0
 order by t.gps
```

Answer (score 0):

So break the problem down.  What you have is a list of all logins followed by the logout.

Getting the list of logins in the order you want is easy

```
 SELECT t1.VEH, t1.DRIVE, t1.TimeStamp
 FROM tablename t1
 WHERE t1.LoginLogoff = 'Login'
 ORDER BY t1.TimeStamp ASC
```

Now you have to "insert" the logouts into this list.  If you just want logout time

The easy way is to do a sub-query and pull the value you want

```
 SELECT t1.VEH, t1.DRIVE, t1.TimeStamp as LoginTS,
    (Select t2.TimeStamp
     FROM tableName t2
     WHERE t2.LoginLogoff = 'Logoff'
       and t1.VEH = t2.VEH
       and t1.DRIVE = t2.DRIVE
       and t2.TimeStamp > t1.TimeStamp
     ORDER BY t2.TimeStamp ASC
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
   ) AS LogoutTS
 FROM tablename t1
 WHERE t1.LoginLogoff = 'Login'
 ORDER BY t1.TimeStamp ASC
```

You could also do it as a join, but I'll leave that up to you.

If you really need two rows you can cross join to a two row table to "pull" out the values you you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase one extra columns and mark it suitable when insert or update this table .It is easy to do so than writing complicate query.

Anyway I have tried with your existing table design only.Also I think you need login-logoff status of per vehicle.
You can try with other sample data and let me know where it is not working.

```
declare @t table(Vehicle varchar(50),GPS datetime,Login_Logoff varchar(50),Driver varchar(50))
insert into @t values
 ('Veh1','2016-01-28 06:30','Login','D1')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 06:35','Login','D1')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 06:40','Login','D1')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 09:40','Logoff','D1')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 10:30','Login','D2')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 12:30','Logoff','D2')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 15:30','Login','D1')
,('Veh1','2016-01-28 17:30','Logoff','D1')

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY vehicle ORDER BY gps
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT vehicle
        ,gps
        ,Login_Logoff
        ,driver
        ,rn
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.vehicle
        ,CASE 
            WHEN b.driver = a.Driver
                AND a.Login_Logoff <> b.Login_Logoff
                THEN a.gps
            WHEN b.driver <> a.Driver
                THEN a.gps
            END
        ,a.login_logoff
        ,a.Driver
        ,b.rn + 1
    FROM cte a
    INNER JOIN CTE1 b ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
    WHERE a.rn <= 8
    )
SELECT vehicle
    ,gps
    ,Login_Logoff
    ,driver
FROM cte1
WHERE gps IS NOT NULL
```